# RichTextBox in a single line in C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Any way to convert a RichTextBox content and convert it to a single line in a String variable?

I have this:

```
string line = Document.Text;  //Convierte el contenido en una sola línea.
string singleLine=line.Replace("\r\n", " ");
```

When show that in a MessageBox, it still appears in multiple lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the newline are still there?. The MessageBox has a finite length of space to show its message. When there is no more space it starts a newline but it doesn't modify anything in your message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MessageBox has a finite length of space to show its message.
When there is no more space it continues to print your text on a newline but it doesn't modify anything in your message.

To check if your code has effectively removed the newlines try to print in the output window with

```
Console.WriteLine(singleline);
```

Also, I prefer to use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of the escape codes specific to the current operating system

```
string singleLine=line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```